# Erro ao abrir Activity: O <aplicativo> parou

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Tenho um arquivo `VigasFragment.java` com um botão que ao ser tocado deve abrir a `Activity` `VigMetBiapsb.java`, porém algum erro ocorre, fechando a aplicação.

VigasFragment.java:

```
public class VigasFragment extends Fragment {

Button btnBiapsb;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vigas_fragment, container, false);

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    btnBiapsb = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.biapsb);
    btnBiapsb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intBiapsb = new Intent(v.getContext(), VigMetBiapsb.class);
            startActivityForResult(intBiapsb, 0);
        }
    });
    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        return rootView;

    }// fecha onCreateView

}
```

VigMetbiapsb.java:

```
    public class VigMetBiapsb extends Activity {

        int porctAlt, porctLarg;

        EditText edtVao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vao);
        final double edtVaoNum = Double.parseDouble(edtVao.getText().toString());

        Button calcBiapsb = (Button) fi

ndViewById(R.id.calc_biapsb);

    TextView secaoBiapsb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vigmet_biapsb);

        // Spinner
        Spinner spnCargas = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_cargas);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spnAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.str_cargas, R.layout.spinner_style);
        spnAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_style);
        spnCargas.setAdapter(spnAdapter);
        // Spinner

        spnCargas.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spnAdpView, View v, int carga, long id) {

                        if(spnAdpView.getItemAtPosition(carga).toString() == "Cargas pequenas"){ porctAlt = 4; porctLarg = 40; }
                        else if(spnAdpView.getItemAtPosition(carga).toString() == "Cargas médias"){ porctAlt = 5; porctLarg = 50; }
                        else { porctAlt = 6; porctLarg = 60; }

                    }// fecha onItemSelected

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){}
                }//fecha OnItemSelectedListener
        ); // fecha setOnItemSelectedListener

        calcBiapsb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(edtVaoNum != 0){
                    double alt = edtVaoNum * porctAlt;
                    double larg = alt / 100 * porctLarg;

                    secaoBiapsb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valorsec);
                    secaoBiapsb.setText(String.valueOf(alt)+" x "+String.valueOf(larg));
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Informe o tamanho do vão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
            }
        });

    } //fecha onCreate
}
```

Acredito que o erro esteja no código da `VigMetBiapsb.java` pois quando deixo apenas o método `onCreate()` dentro da classe `VigMetBiapsb`, a `Activity` abre normalmente.

[Erros do LogCat](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/47/1416771043-l1.png) ao tocar no botão `btnBiapsb`

[Erros do LogCat](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/47/1416771079-l2.png) ao tocar no botão `btnBiapsb`

Comment: Edeilton, não podemos adivinhar o problema sem você incluir o **stacktrace** sobre o erro. Se puder, inclua-o na sua pergunta.

Comment: Tem razão, @Wakim. Editei a pergunta, acredito que agora esteja mais clara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que esta inicializando suas `View's` na declaração das mesmas dentro da `Activity`. O que faz com que o método `findViewById` seja chamado no construtor da sua `Activity`. E nesse momento a sua `View` ainda não foi construída, gerando o `NullPointerException`.

Migre essa inicialização toda para o `onCreate`, após o `setContentView`, assim como as demais inicializações que você faz.

Mude de:

```
public class VigMetBiapsb extends Activity {

    EditText edtVao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vao);
    final double edtVaoNum = Double.parseDouble(edtVao.getText().toString());
    Button calcBiapsb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc_biapsb);

    // ...
}
```

Para:

```
public class VigMetBiapsb extends Activity {

    int porctAlt, porctLarg;
    double edtVaoNum;

    EditText edtVao;
    Button calcBiapsb;
    TextView secaoBiapsb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Sua inicializacao atual...

        edtVao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vao);

        // Isso nao vai dar erro? edtVao esta preenchido nesse momento?
        edtVaoNum = Double.parseDouble(edtVao.getText().toString());

        calcBiapsb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc_biapsb);
    }
}
```

Comment: O erro foi realmente por causa da inicialização, só que ainda estou enfrentando dois problemas:
A variável `edtVaoNum` não está preenchida no momento em que é inicializada, então a `Activity` ainda não abre.
E se eu utilizar o campo `android:text=""` desta `EditText` com qualquer valor, a `Activity` abre, porém mesmo que eu modifique o valor depois (na interface do usuário) o cálculo é feito com o valor preenchido no código.

Comment: O mesmo ocorre com o Spinner que na inicialização possui o valor "Cargas grandes", que se encaixa no `else { porctAlt = 6; porctLarg = 60; }`. Logo, mesmo após eu selecionar outra opção no Spinner, o cálculo sempre é feito com `porctAlt = 6; porctLarg = 60;`.

Comment: O problema do `Spinner` é que está comparando `String` da forma errada (com `==`), use o método `equals` para comparar objetos. No caso do `edtVaoNum` você não deve inicializar ele no `onCreate`, porque o valor ainda não foi digitado pelo usuário. Você deve setar o valor `edtVaoNum` apenas dentro do `onClick` do `calcBiapsb`.

Comment: Funcionou e entendi perfeitamente, muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

acho que você não precisa dar esse startActivityForResult(intBiapsb, 0);
e sim so um starActivity(intBiapsb);